# How can I set the lower bound on the x axis for a google chart?

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I'm trying set the x range on a date based google bar chart. I'd like the year of the chart to start at January 1, even though the data doesn't start until April.

I've seen a number of suggestions for how to set the min and max vertical range, but I could not make them work on the x axis. I don't know if the issue is the x-axis, or the fact that I'm using dates as my x axis. I do get this error when I try to set a min

"a.getTime is not a function"

Here's my working code, with no limits:

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn("date", "Season Start Date")
data.addColumn("number", "Acres Burned")
var options = {
    "title": "US Fire data TBD!!!",
    "hAxis": {
        "title": "Year"
    },
    "vAxis": {
        "title": "Total Acres Burned"
    }
}
data.addRows([
[new Date(2021, 5, 12), 1000],
[new Date(2021, 5, 14), 400],
[new Date(2021, 5, 15), 0],
[new Date(2021, 5, 16), -39],
[new Date(2021, 5, 17), 165],
[new Date(2021, 5, 18), 0],
[new Date(2021, 5, 19), 1000],
[new Date(2021, 5, 20), 1000],
]);
var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById("us_chart"))
chart.draw(data, options);
```

This code renders the error message ("a.getTime is not a function"), instead of the chart:

```
var options = {
    "title": "US Fire data TBD!!!",
    "hAxis": {
        "title": "Year",
        "viewWindowMode":"explicit",
        "viewWindow": {
          "min": "new Date(2021, 5, 1)",
          "max": "new Date(2021, 8, 1)"
        }

    },
    "vAxis": {
        "title": "Total Acres Burned"
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the min / max values for the axis should be dates, not strings.

```
var options = {
    "title": "US Fire data TBD!!!",
    "hAxis": {
        "title": "Year",
        "viewWindow": {
          "min": new Date(2021, 5, 1),
          "max": new Date(2021, 8, 1)
        }

    },
    "vAxis": {
        "title": "Total Acres Burned"
    }
}
```

and the following option isn't necessary...

```
"viewWindowMode":"explicit",
```

Comment: D'oh! Thank you!